# How may read json file partycular with (js/node.js)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to read users list from json file ,but I want Read only one I use node.js fs module`

```
app.get("/1",function(req,res)
```

`{ fs.readfile("users.json",function(data,err){res.write(data)}}`
When there is /1 i want to open first user and when /2 the second

Comment: fs.createReadstream("users.json").pipe(res); is much better. Also have a look at *nodejs parse json*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, load the json into the RAM on Serverstart so that you dont have to reread every time:

```
var users=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("users.json","utf-8"));
```

Now you could use Express features:

```
//if theres a param ( a dynamic url) called user, lets place the user with that id into the property user of the request
app.param("user",function(req,res,next,id){
  req.user=users[id];
  next();
});

//if theres a request to user/1 the upper code will be executed with id=1, and well return our user
app.get("user/:user",function(req,res){
  res.json(req.user);
});
```

Note that using param is not neccessary, however its easier to extend the programm. Now you could visit:

```
//localhost/user/1
```

The upper code requires users.json to be:

```
[
{name:test},
.. 
]
```

If you want user/ to return all:

```
app.get("user/",function(req,res){
  res.json(users);
});
```